# ServiceStack.Razor CustomHttpHandler not displaying for HttpStatusCode.BadRequest

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to get a minimal app working using ServiceStack.Razor, and I'm having trouble getting a CustomHttpHandler to work. I've followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice) and [here](http://razor.servicestack.net/), but it's not working right.

I'm using the following code to register a custom http handler for `HttpStatusCode.BadRequest`:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    this.Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());
    this.SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
    {
        CustomHttpHandlers =
        {
            { HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new RazorHandler("/notfound") }, 
            { HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new RazorHandler("/error") }
        }, 
        DebugMode = true
     });
}
```

The thing is, the `/notfound` handler works perfectly for 404s, but no matter what I do, I can't get the `/error` razor file to display whenever an `ArgumentNullException` is thrown.

My service method looks like this:

```
public object Any(Hello request)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Name))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Name");
    }

    return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello " + request.Name };
}
```

ServiceStack returns a 400 status, which is fine, but it still displays the view I have for `HelloResponse`:

[image: 400-bad-request]

What am I missing? Am I misunderstanding how CustomHttpHandlers are supposed to work?

For reference, I put the project [up on github](https://github.com/rossipedia/ServiceStackTest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah the CustomHttpHandlers are just meant for handling un-handled system generated errors. Currently they're limited to:

- **NotFound (404)** for un-handled requests
- **Forbidden (403)** when a request is made to an forbidden file or resource

These are the errors happen outside of ServiceStack and so isn't able to be handled by [existing ServiceStack's event hooks or user-defined custom logic](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations), so we allow users to modify the behavior in this case via `CustomHttpHandlers`.

The [Error Handling wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling) describes how to handle errors in ServiceStack.

Though it might make sense (since it's opt-in) to allow a fallback after the exception is handled to allow it to be further handled by rendering it to a user-specified page, that you're expecting to do here.

We'll look at trying to explore something like this in the future. Feel free to add future feature requests like these to [ServiceStack's issue list](http://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues) so we don't forget.

Comment: How would I go about returning a Razor View from the `HandleServiceExceptionDelegate`? Or should I post that as a new question?